# How to center an HTML element using jQuery and CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to center some html elements in my html page, for example a label. I want to accomplish this by using jQuery and CSS. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with jQuery.

I just need a little help from you guys.

Thank you.

Comment: You need `CSS` for that and not `jQuery`. And it is not possible to help without posting the **HTML**

Comment: Ok let me update my question then.

Comment: Hold on why down vote? I'm just asking a question and looking for an answer. If my question doesn't meet your requirement like putting "HTML" please leave it as it is. I really appreciate those three people provided me these answer. This will help me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Try this simple function:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}

//Use the above function as:
$(element).center();
```

Comment: Alright let me try this.

Comment: Nice, but why are you adding 2 ?

Comment: the half of space of difference between container and element

Comment: to get the center of the screen, eg
(800 - 400 )/ 2+100

Comment: This will not accommodate for if the window is resized.. also is likely to run before the element is loaded...

Comment: also shoud run the function , on $(window).resize(function(){...

Answer (score 3):

Presentation is **NOT** a task for jQuery.

CSS:

```
label {display:block;text-align:center}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the best way to do this is through pure css, but this is a very brute force way to do it....

**HTML**

```
<div id="centerme">content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#centerme {
  position: absolute;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).onLoad(this.resize);
$(window).resize(this.resize);

resize = function() {
  var center = ($(window).width/2) - ($('#centerme').width/2);
  $('.centerme').css('left', center+'px');
}
```

Comment: This is interesting as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/tGbxj/1/

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    verCenter('#red');
    verCenter('#blue');
    
    $(window).resize(function(){
        verCenter('#red');
        verCenter('#blue');
    });
});

function verCenter(element){
    var ver_top = ($(window).height() - $(element).height()) / 2;
    $(element).css( "margin-top", ver_top+'px' );
}
```

Comment: Cool pure JQuery. Thank you.

Comment: Check my update answer again, now you only need to call function and pass the element. That's all. Resizing also works.

Comment: Do you have a demo for this update as well?

Comment: I would appreciate that.

Comment: Yes, here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/tGbxj/1/... also in my answer :)